# ProGuard - Use unique field names?

Tags: java, proguard

I'm using ProGuard to obfuscate my source code, but I'm running into a problem where my obfuscated code re-uses the same field name for fields with different types. For example:

```
public class Pojo {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Becomes:

```
public class Pojo {
    int a;
    String a;
}
```

This is causing problems when trying to use JSON serialization/deserialization, so I'd like to have unique field names instead.

I tried adding `-useuniqueclassmembernames` though it didn't work. Couldn't see any other options, besides maybe using the `-obfuscationdictionary` option, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: If you're using Java reflection to serialize/deserialize, you're going to run into a lot more problems than that. Whenever you update your code, Proguard might change the names of some fields, which will break your JSON serialization format. If the names of the fields are significant for reflection purposes, then they shouldn't be obfuscated.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. I'm using Gson, so can add @SerializedName to my fields to get around that issue. I guess I was just curious if there was an easy way to configure it to not reuse field names within the same class. :)